# Order the odd numbers from an array in a descending order

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, srand

I am making a code that will:

1. print an array of random numbers
2. order it to an ascending order
3. find the odd numbers from that array
4. arrange the odd numbers to a descending order.

I've done the first three but I can't arrange the odd numbers to a descending order. The program sorts the random numbers to a descending order instead of just the odd numbers. Please help me. Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    int size,i,j,temp;
    int a[50];

    printf("Enter array size| ");
    scanf("%i",&size);

    srand(time(0));

    printf("\nThe Random Numbers| \n");
    for(i=0;i<size;i++){
        a[i] = rand()%100;
        printf("%i, ",a[i]);
    }

    for (i=0;i<size;++i)
    {
        for (j=i+1;j<size;++j)
        {
            if (a[i]>a[j])
            {
                temp=a[i];
                a[i]=a[j];
                a[j]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\n\nThe Ascending Order of Random Numbers| \n");
    for (i=0;i<size;++i)
        printf("%d, ", a[i]);


    printf("\n\nThe Odd Numbers| \n");
    for(i=0;i<size;i++){
        if(a[i]%2!=0){
            printf("%i, ",a[i]);
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<size;i++){
        for(j=i+1;j<size;j++){
            if(a[i]<a[j])
            {
                temp=a[i];
                a[i]=a[j];
                a[j]=temp;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("\n\nThe Descending Order of Odds| \n");
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
        printf("%d ",a[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the `k` for? shouldn't it be `i`?

Comment: Yeah, I was experimenting earlier (overlaying for loops) and I forgot to change it back to i. Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider `n` to be array `length -1` and look at the following pseudo code:

```
for each i in n {
      if a[i] even:
          continue
      for each j in n {
          if a[j] even:
              continue
          if(a[i]<a[j])
              swap(a[i], a[j])
      }
}
```

In this case you ignore the even number and modify only the array places who contains odd value.

This is `c` code:

```
for(i=0;i<size;i++){
    if(a[i]%2!=0) {
        for(j=i+1;j<size;j++){
            if((a[j]%2!=0) && (a[i]<a[j]))
            {
                t=a[i];
                a[i]=a[j];
                a[j]=t;
            }
        } // end of j for loop
    } // end of if odd
} // end of i for loop
```